# Angular directive assign same scope with multi behaviour

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive with `refresh` scope. In my case refresh should be an **object** or a **function**, so how can i assign this to my directive.

## 1. First case

```
<!--HTML-->
<directive 
  refresh="vm.refresh">
</directive>

//JS
scope:{refresh:"="}
```

## 2. Second case

```
<directive 
  refresh="vm.refresh(search)">
</directive>

//JS
scope:{refresh:"&"}
```

## 3. My case

```
<directive 
  refresh="vm.refresh or vm.refresh(search)">
</directive>

//JS - What to do ? need help
scope:{refresh:"=&needHelp"}
```

But i need this both features in my directive, So how can i ***isolate*** this both. I need to know applied ***refresh*** scope is **object** OR **function** in link function of directive.

Comment: And how  refresh is going to be used in case of `refresh="vm.refresh"`?

Comment: @dfsq I mentioned in case1 & case2.  Refer HTML portion of these cases

Comment: Probably you should use an attribute for the object and one for the method, not the same.

Comment: @Michelem This is the question OP's is asking: how to distinguish what was passed into directive.

Comment: I think using `=` you can then check (in the directive) what kind of variable you have, because `=` copies the scope as it is

Comment: @Michelem No, it will not work, because with `=` the first case will result into function that can be called from directive - ok, but the second case will be `undefined` (because it will be executed during parse phase) - totally not what we want.

Answer (score 2):

This is tricky situation. In such case you could check for what type of expression `refresh` attribute holds. However, you need to parse attribute value manually with the help of `$parse` service.

```
.directive('directive', function($parse) {
  return {
    scope: {
      // some other bindings, scope is isolated
    },
    template: '<button ng-click="test()">Test</button>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      // parse attribute expression (not evaluated yet)
      var callback = $parse(attrs.refresh);

      scope.search = 'Search query';

      scope.test = function() {

        // when needed to refresh: evaluate refresh callback
        var evalled = callback(scope.$parent, {search: scope.search});
        if (typeof evalled == 'function') {
          evaled(scope.search);
        }
      };
    }
  };
})
```

In case of `refresh="vm.refresh(search)"` situation `callback(scope.$parent, {search: scope.search})` will do the trick. However, if this evaluation returns a function, it means that this is `refresh="vm.refresh"` case - then it enters the `if` block and executes this function with necessary parameter.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/4W0SKOzpL5LUP0OAofp5?p=info

Comment: Excellent. Going to try

Comment: Here some problem, If alert in else then second button nt wrking properly. http://plnkr.co/edit/MYlyfX70qkkNN2zbKKLu?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You can use expression binding to evaluate the scope variable, and use the `$attrs` object to determine the type. Refer to example below...

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g4bft6rL/

JS

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            refresh: '&'
        },
        controller: function ($scope, $attrs) {
            $scope.$watch('refresh', function (prev, curr) {
                $scope.text = 'refresh is a ' + getExpressionType($attrs.refresh);
                $scope.value = $scope.refresh();
            });
        },
        template: "result: {{ text }} = {{ value }}"
    };

    function getExpressionType (expression) {
        // naive, but you get the idea
        return expression.slice(-1)[0] === ')' ? 'function' : 'object';
    }
});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.refresh = { a: 1 };
    $scope.refreshFn = function what (arg) {
        return {
            value: arg
        };
    };
    $scope.param = 123;
}
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <my-directive refresh="refreshFn(param)"></my-directive>
  <my-directive refresh="refresh"></my-directive>
</div>
```

Comment: No, this is not reliable at all and should not be used. Quick example: `<my-directive refresh="data = param"></my-directive>` will fail while this is `refresh="refreshFn(param)"` case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below, I havent tested this code but just consider the hint/idea.

```
<directive refresh="refreshFromOuter" search="outerSearchString">" </directive>
```

refreshFromOuter can be a string or function.
in directive controller

```
 return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            name: '=',
          refresh:'=',
          search:'@'
        }, 
        controller:function($scope){
            console.log($scope);
          if(angular.isFunction($scope.show)){
            alert('is Function');
            $scope.refresh($scope.search || '');
          }
          else{
            alert($scope.refresh + 'as string');
          }
        },
        template: '<div>Some template</div>'
    };
```